# Why do some archers wear two gloves?

Tags: gear, archery

I've recently noticed that some archers wear two gloves and some only one. Latter always have them on the hand which pulls the string.

Two gloves:
[image: Two gloves]

One glove:
[image: One glove]

What's the difference? Is it up to their personal preferences?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On a longbow you rest the arrow on your hand. If you do it for many hours it can cause irritation so some wear a glove to avoid this.

As for the hand pulling the string it is another form of a finger tab. I have a three fingered glove. It's a matter of preference for this. I found a glove more comfortable than a finger tab.

Comment: the glove on the bow hand also protects the hand from damage incase of a bad loose, or scratches from the fletchings

Comment: @jammypeach: Exactly, and it can be more than scratches. If the front of one of the fletches gets a bit loose it can quite painfully insert itself into your hand/skin which is holding the bow (been there).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't usually feel irritation on my grip hand from either the arrow or the fletchings. However I have felt the need to wear one occasionally when I've got that one odd handmade bow in the bunch that just loves to slap my hand.

That said, I do pull a pretty strong longbow and finger pain can definitely ruin a good practice session and may even some day cost me a long sought after trophy. Because of this, a very comfortable set of finger tabs. (Rubber rather than leather) as I feel like I have slightly better control, and I believe it turns my string just a wee bit better.

All in all, my choice is for the finger tabs only. The second glove always seems to make me feel like I've got too much gear between myself and the shot.

Comment: Though interesting, this doens't really answer the question.